# how to set creation date & time with milliseconds to file?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, milliseconds

i am trying to set creation date and time to file with milliseconds . but won't works by my way .

```
setfile -d "01/23/2000 12:00:00.099" file.txt
setfile -m "01/23/2001 12:00:00.499" file.txt
```

and so on

this way only set from Hours to seconds . not milliseconds 
how to do this ??

Comment: Apple new APFS filesystem can support nano seconds and more great feature it had ! so when i see somewhere should be exist how to change or update file birthdate and time with nanoseconds..  haha your tech-power is old ! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Just use coreutils [touch](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html):

```
touch --date '01/23/2000 12:00:00.099' file.txt
```

Comment: did you have test  your way on macos ??

Comment: No. I based on the manual and [some research](http://blog.grapii.com/2010/07/change-a-files-creationmodified-date-on-mac-os-x/) how to use `touch` to change creation date of a file. They use `touch -t ... file` with a timestamp. The `--date` is the same as `touch -t`, only format is more `date --date` like

Comment: I think I will delete the answer then, right? Or is it possible to `brew install coreutils` on macos and get gnu's touch on macos?

Comment: --date '01/23/2000 12:00:00.099' file.txt ,  this way  only for new created file , but  can't update creation date and time .. later then only can be updated modified date time .. ok ??  Apple new APFS filesystem can support  nano seconds and more great feature it had !  so when i see somewhere  should be  exist  how to change or update file birthdate and time with nanoseconds..

Comment: This works using GNU touch on macOS (installable via `brew install coreutils`).